# Can't run Numpy and Matplotlib on VSCode

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, visual-studio-code

Im trying to run a simple python script that imports numpy and matplotlib on VS Code to plot a vector but I get the error

```
QSocketNotifier: Can only be used with threads started with QThread
```

Seems like a C++ problem but how can I get past this because I just want to run the python script?

Here's my python code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Defining the vector v
v = np.array([1, 1])

# Create axis of plot as axis
axis = plt.axes()
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message “QSocketNotifier: Can only be used with threads started with QThread” is related to the Qt library, which is used by matplotlib for rendering. This error can occur when the Qt event loop is not properly initialized.

To bypass this error, switch to a different backend for matplotlib: Matplotlib can use different backends for rendering. You can switch to a different backend that doesn’t rely on Qt. For example, you can use the `Agg` backend which is a raster graphics backend and is known for its efficiency. You can switch to the Agg backend by adding the following line at the beginning of your script:

```py
import matplotlib

matplotlib.use('Agg')
```